# favicon.svg not showing in title bar

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

I have worked on this for days trying to solve the problem. I can't get the favicon.svg to show up on my browser (using latest Chrome).

The source file is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 48 48"><path stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" d="M6,6 L21,21 M6,21 L21,6"/></svg>
```

The icon shows **fine** in the main screen if I navigate to http://MYSITEHERE/favicon.svg

BUT it does **not** show up when I navigate to http://MYSITEHERE

The website is working otherwise and starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Administrator Login - CLO Web Design</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" sizes="any">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>....
```

Any ideas? I have scoured the web trying to find answers. Most places say to include the

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" sizes="any">
```

and it will be fine (which I have). Its also 48x48 which should be accepted by Google. Why not?

Many thanks.

[Update 28/12/2022 based on Sebastian Simon's help - see below]

[image: Dev tools output for favicon]

[image: favicon still doesn't show]

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? SVG favicons are supported in recent Firefox and Chromium based browsers, but not necessary others. PNG might be a safer approach. Also, browsers cache favicons, even broken ones, you might need a browser restart to see favicons in the browser tab.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, is it blocked by an extension or the browser? Which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly. Is the MIME type correct? Look into the **Response** tab inside the Network tab: do you receive what you expect?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I just did that and got the output above (see edit to my question)

Comment: Seems like you’re receiving HTML instead of SVG. Now look at the **Response** tab (instead of the **Header** tab): what actually is the HTML? If it is still the same SVG content, does it work if you include `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top of the SVG file (otherwise this is technically not a valid SVG file)?

Comment: Great, you solved it Sabastian. i have updated my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian Simon (see above comments) solved this:

Include

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at the top of the SVG file (otherwise this is technically not a valid SVG file)"

Kudos to him for solving it... Many thanks.

I have however decided to stick with this embedded solution:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewbox='0 0 64 64'><path stroke='black' stroke-linecap='round' d='M6,6 L21,21 M6,21 L21,6'/></svg>" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

This is probably more efficient preventing the additional favicon request...

(PS. ignore the icon data which is just an "x" - I intend to change that.)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the type also: **type="image/svg+xml"** and make sure that the path is correct. Check the browser console for any loading errors that might suggest you are using the wrong relative path.

```html
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just tried your suggestion, yet it still doesn't work. I've already tried many combinations of <link etc> with no luck. I forgot to mention my website has no domain linked up to it yet - just a string of 4 numbers. Perhaps Chrome doesn't allow favicons in that case? Not sure...